# Parse substring to double directly

Tags: c#, .net, f#

If I have a string such as `1 2 3` and I identify the position of a substring containing a `double`, how can I parse it directly from the substring without creating a temporary string?

For example, I could do `System.Double.Parse(str.Substring(0, 1))` but that would create a temporary string which is slow and needless. Is it possible to parse a double directly from part of the original string?

**EDIT**

Eric Lippert has questioned my motives here, stating that "Small strings are cheap". The motivation for this comes from my doing the same thing for the parsing of ints and seeing a massive performance improvements because, apparently, small strings are not so cheap.

Here is a function that lexes a sequence of ints via temporary strings:

```
let lex f (s: string) =
  let rec inside i0 (s: string, i) =
    if i = s.Length then
      f (s.Substring(i0, i-i0) |> System.Int32.Parse)
    else
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0'<=c && c<='9' then
        inside i0 (s, i+1)
      else
        f (s.Substring(i0, i-i0) |> System.Int32.Parse)
        outside (s, i)
  and outside (s: string, i) =
    if i < s.Length then
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0'<=c && c<='9' then
        inside i (s, i)
      else
        outside (s, i+1)
  outside (s, 0)
```

This takes 2.4s to lex 15,625,000 ints from a string.

Here is a version that avoids temporary strings:

```
let lex f (s: string) =
  let rec inside n (s: string, i) =
    if i = s.Length then f n else
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0'<=c && c<='9' then
        inside (10*n + int c - int '0') (s, i+1)
      else
        f n
        outside (s, i)
  and outside (s: string, i) =
    if i < s.Length then
      let c = s.[i]
      if '0'<=c && c<='9' then
        inside 0 (s, i)
      else
        outside (s, i+1)
  outside (s, 0)
```

This takes 0.255s, over 9x faster than the solution that uses temporary strings!

I see no reason why lexing floats should be any different. Therefore, by not providing the ability to parse a float from a substring .NET is leaving an order of magnitude in performance on the table. I do a lot of scientific computing and often have to lex large amounts of data, especially at startup, so I really don't want to throw performance to the wind like this.

Comment: Seems like an extreme micro-optimization to me. You're going to either need a library, or write a fully-fledged double parser, which isn't exactly a simple task.

Comment: Do you actually have an identified performance problem here?  Small strings are cheap. That said, of course you can write a lexer that only copies individual characters.

Comment: @EricLippert: I have updated the question with benchmark code for parsing ints without creating temporaries and it is over 9x faster. I assume parsing floats would see similarly-huge performance gains. Suffice to say, I would not say that "small strings are cheap".

Comment: Well, there's cheap and then there's cheap enough; something can be cheap and still too expensive. If the memory and time burden of creating small strings is *not cheap enough* then write your own code that *is* cheap enough, which you've done. Problem solved; the system works.

Comment: Yes. The frustration is that everything I need is already in .NET but buried behind an API that cripples performance by restricting the input to a complete string rather than allowing substring inputs. Ideally .NET would provide an overload for `Parse` functions accepting a string, start index and length. After all, I'd imagine almost every practical application of the `Parse` functions is actually acting upon a substring anyway...

Comment: I have gone down that path in the past for similar cases. The starter code is easy, but the more robust you want your `Double.Parse` to be, the slower the `Double.Parse` gets. You still get the benefit of avoiding creation of strings. A few factors to consider while writing your code.  `Locale` handling, different float point format (fixed, exponential, etc) you want to support, how you handle spaces and zeroes at strategic places, +/- signs, NaN, inifinity, etc. In my case, I could control a bunch of above specified factors, so my code was not as generic as the .NET Framework's

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's totally doable. You can write your own function to do parsing, you can even base it on [actual](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,78ddf2a0973205dd) source code of `Double.Parse()`. This code doesn't look big and scary and I think you can optimize it even more for your needs.

Comment: The [actual worker method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,04291cc3a0b10032) is 200 lines on dense, unsafe C# with deeply nested looping and branching. And that's besides the auxiliary helper types/methods. I would not not dismiss this so casually. (Not to mention the requirement of `/unsafe` means one's assembly is no longer verifiable and has various other potentially-unpalatable restrictions)

Comment: For some types of tasks it can worth it. I think, not having substring is not a big optimization, but parsing function itself has a great potential for optimization.

Comment: "the requirement of /unsafe". Eh? They bit twiddled the performance out of it so much they used unsafe code and then they go and wrap it in an API that forces you to copy substrings so it is grindingly slow. Nuts!

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the string digit by digit, something like this:

```
static double CustomConvertToDouble(string input, int startIndex, int length)
{
    double result = 0d;
    int lastDigitIndex = startIndex + length - 1;
    int power = 0;
    for (int i = lastDigitIndex; i >= startIndex; i--)
    {
        int digit = (input[i] - '0');
        result += (Math.Pow(10, power++)) * digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
string tmp = "1 2 3";
double result = CustomConvertToDouble(tmp, 0, 1);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 1
```

You could expand on this to take decimal points etc. into account.

But I really doubt if the normal way can be a performance bottleneck and I'm interested to know why you want to go to the trouble. If that piece of code is really that performance-critical, maybe the best route is writing it in another language?

Comment: I think this would be many many many times slower than `System.Double.Parse(str.Substring(0, 1))`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that part of the answer, I've removed from the comment

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for single digits, it's easy enough:

```
let readDigit s i =
    let getDigit x =
        if '0' <= x && x <= '9'
        then byte x - 48uy // byte value of '0'
        else failwith "Not a digit"
    s |> Seq.item i |> getDigit |> double
```

This F# implementation utilises that `string` implements `char seq`, and that a `char` value can be converted to a `byte` value.

I doubt that it's faster than using `Double.Parse(str.Substring(0, 1))`, though.

Comment: Wasn't me. However, that code is going to be extremely slow! :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < input.Length; x++)
{
    if(input[x] != ' ')
        Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(input[x].ToString()));
}
```

Doesn't create any extra Enumerable objects, but Double.Parse only excepts strings so a toString is required.

Answer (score -2):

This is the best you can do

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "1 2 3";
    double[] output = input.Split(new char[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This adds additional allocations of 3 arrays, an `IEnumerable`, and a `Func`. Considering OP is intolerant of even a single string allocation, I don't think this fits the request.

Comment: Worse, you've made all of the temporaries long lived by keeping them in an array so they will survive two generations each time paying for marking, evacuation and pointer updates so that solution is probably 40x slower than necessary.

Comment: I know, but the request was for "parse directly".  Avoiding temporary variables does necessarily increase speed with the optimizing compiler.  Going to linq is not the most efficient method.  If columns are fixed width substring would probably be more efficient than Split() method, but if columns are not fixed Split() would be more efficient.

Comment: @jdweng Well the idea here is to not create any strings at all. Everything needed to parse the float is in the original string so it doesn't make sense to copy it into another string before parsing it.

Comment: Where did I copy a string?  I just added code for testing.